# Image upload with PHP and AJAX not working

Tags: javascript, php

In my current project i want to update the users profile image with a AJAX post. In the past i update the image with an normal PHP function. So I used my working function and implement this in my new AJAX post.

If the form is triggered the function will be called, but the new image will not be uploaded or recognized.
So the second if in the function will not be called although there is an image.

In the response of the POST I ever get the 5 and 0.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
update_user_informations();

function update_user_informations() {

    include "../../../includes/db.php";
    
    if(isset($_POST['update_user_informations'])) {

        $targetDir = "../../../assets/img/users/";

        $allowed_image_extensions = array(
            "png","jpg","jpeg"
        );

        $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
        $user_logo_old = $_POST['user_logo_old'];

        if(isset($_FILES['user_logo']) && !empty($_FILES['user_logo']['name'])) {

            $fileinfo = @getimagesize($_FILES['user_logo']['tmp_name']);
            $width = $fileinfo[0];
            $height = $fileinfo[1];

            $user_image = $pathinfo($_FILES['user_logo']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
            if(!in_array($user_image, $allowed_image_extensions)) {
                echo 1;
                exit;
            } else if(($_FILES['user_logo']['size'] > 1048576)) {
                echo 2;
                exit;
            } else if($width > "500" || $height > "500") {
                echo 3;
                exit;
            } else {
                unlink("../../../assets/img/users/$user_logo_old");
                $user_logo_new = $user_id.$user_username;

                echo 4;
            }

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['user_logo']['tmp_name'], $targetDir.$user_logo_new.".".$user_image);

            $user_logo_path = $user_logo_new.".".$user_image;

        } else {

            $get_user_logo = $connection->prepare("SELECT user_logo FROM user WHERE user_id = ?");
            $get_user_logo->bind_param("s", $user_id);
            $get_user_logo->execute();
            $result = $get_user_logo->get_result();
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();

            $user_logo_path = $row['user_logo'];

            $get_user_logo->close();

            echo 5;
        }

        $update_user_informations = $connection->prepare("UPDATE user SET user_logo = ? WHERE user_id = ?");
        $update_user_informations->bind_param("ss", $user_logo_path, $user_id);
        $update_user_informations->execute();
        $update_user_informations->close();

        echo 0;
        exit;
    }
}
```

```
"use strict";
var KTAccountSettingsBasicInfo = (function () {
  const e = document.getElementById("kt_account_basic_info_form");
  return {
    init: function () {
      (() => {
          const o = e.querySelector("#kt_account_basic_info_submit");
          o.addEventListener("click", function (t) {
            t.preventDefault(),
              o.setAttribute("data-kt-indicator", "on"),
              (o.disabled = !0),
              setTimeout(function () {
                o.removeAttribute("data-kt-indicator"),
                  (o.disabled = !1),
                  Swal.fire({
                    text: "Form has been successfully submitted!",
                    icon: "success",
                    buttonsStyling: !1,
                    confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                    customClass: { confirmButton: "btn btn-primary" },
                  }).then(function (t) {
                    t.isConfirmed;

                    $.ajax({
                      url: "../profile/includes/settings/profile-settings-functions.php",
                      method: "POST",
                      data: $('#kt_account_basic_info_form').serialize(),
                      success: function(response) {
                        if(response == 1) {
                          Swal.fire({
                            text: "Wrong image extension!",
                            icon: "error",
                            buttonsStyling: !1,
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                            customClass: { confirmButton: "btn btn-primary" },
                          })
                        } else if(response == 2) {
                          Swal.fire({
                            text: "The image must not be larger than 1MB!",
                            icon: "error",
                            buttonsStyling: !1,
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                            customClass: { confirmButton: "btn btn-primary" },
                          })
                        } else if(response == 3) {
                          Swal.fire({
                            text: "The image must not be larger than 500px x 500px!",
                            icon: "error",
                            buttonsStyling: !1,
                            confirmButtonText: "Ok, got it!",
                            customClass: { confirmButton: "btn btn-primary" },
                          })
                        } else {
                          location.reload();
                        }
                      }
                    });
                  });
              }, 2e3);
          })
      })();
    },
  };
})();
KTUtil.onDOMContentLoaded(function () {
  KTAccountSettingsBasicInfo.init();
});
```

```
<div class="card mb-5 mb-xl-10" id="kt_account_settings_info" data-kt-scroll-offset="{default: 100, md: 125}">
                        <div class="card-header border-0 cursor-pointer" role="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#kt_account_basic_info" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="kt_account_basic_info">
                            <div class="card-title m-0">
                                <h3 class="fw-boldest m-0">Basic Info</h3>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div id="kt_account_basic_info" class="collapse show">
                            <form id="kt_account_basic_info_form" class="form">
                                <div class="card-body border-top p-9">
                                    <input class='d-none' name='update_user_informations' value='1'>
                                    <input class='d-none' name='user_id' value='<?php echo $user_id ?>'>
                                    <input class='d-none' name='user_logo_old' value='<?php echo $user_logo ?>'>
                                    <div class="row mb-6">
                                        <label class="col-lg-4 col-form-label fw-bold fs-6">Avatar</label>
                                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                                            <div class="image-input image-input-outline" data-kt-image-input="true" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/users/blank.png)">
                                                <div class="image-input-wrapper w-125px h-125px" style="background-image: url(../assets/img/users/<?php echo $user_logo ?>)"></div>
                                                <label class="btn btn-icon btn-circle btn-active-color-primary w-25px h-25px bg-white shadow" data-kt-image-input-action="change" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" title="Change avatar">
                                                    <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill fs-7"></i>
                                                    <input type="file" name="user_logo" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg">
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="form-text">Allowed file types: png, jpg, jpeg.</div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-footer d-flex justify-content-end py-6 px-9">
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="kt_account_basic_info_submit">Save Changes</button>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: Is there any console error? Also here is a reference that worked for me. https://www.cloudways.com/blog/the-basics-of-file-upload-in-php/

Comment: Dear use enctype="multipart/form-data" in form tag.